# How to apply grepl for data frame

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I want to use `grepl` for multiple patterns defined as a data frame. 
`df_sen` is presented as

```
sentence
"She would like to go there"
"I had it few days ago"
"We have spent few millions"
```

`df_triggers` is presented as follows:

```
trigger
few days
few millions
```

And I want to create a matrix where sentence `x` triggers and on the intersection to see `1` if trigger was found in a sentence and `0` if it was not.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
matrix <- grepl(df_triggers$trigger, df_sen$sentence)
```

But I see the error message that I have more than 1 pattern in `grepl()`.

The desired output is:

```
                                 few days    few millions
"She would like to go there"        0              0
"I had it few days ago"             1              0
"We have spent few millions         0              1
```

Comment: And the thing is that I have 2500 sentences. So I cannot implement it like `few days | few millions`

Comment: Try an sapply loop over the patterns: `sapply(df_triggers$trigger, grepl, df_sen$sentence)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thank you! It worked well!

Comment: You're welcome. Please post it as a solution

Comment: It would be better if you could post the solution as an answer below the question. Thanks!

Comment: @djhurio thank you for your comment. Posted there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sapply(df_triggers$trigger, grepl, df_sen$sentence)
```

from @docendodiscimus worked.