# Sapply grepl data frames exact/complete matches

Tags: r, match, sapply, grepl, exact-match

I have the same problem as in :

[How to apply grepl for data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936428/how-to-apply-grepl-for-data-frame)

But I'm getting undesired matches, as in :

[Complete word matching using grepl in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528258/complete-word-matching-using-grepl-in-r)

How do I apply the \< or \b solution in a sapply environment when grepl is looping through vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself.
It's sufficient to paste a blank space before and after each element in the vector to be matched with the sentences.

```
vector <- paste(" ", vector, " ")

matches <- sapply(vector, grepl, sentences, ignore.case=TRUE )
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd used an anonymous function to be applied to each element of the columns in the data frame.

```
vec1 <- c("I don't want to match this", "This is what I want to match")
vec2 <- c('Why would I match this?', "What is a good match for this?")

df <- data.frame(vec1,vec2)

sapply(df, function(x) grepl("\\<is\\>", x))

      vec1  vec2
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I need is a bit different, as in the first link.
A vector contains sentences, the other words. I need a matrix showing me which sentences contain which words, but only if they are complete. So I should apply the function you are describing to a vector I guess, not sure how to do it though. Thanks for your help.